# Output with 3 dots and 2 dots, read from right to left

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I get an exit behind a series of commands that returns me a huge list of servers.

Which start like this:

```
...linux.sapsmftexp01 ...linux.sappiftexp01 ...linux.sapbwftexp01
..linux.radiuswifiexp01 ..linux.gitlabexp01 ..linux.redisccexp01
```

I need to get only the name information, i.e .:

```
sapsmftexp01
sappiftexp01
sapbwftexp01
```

When I have tried to do it with `cut -d`

It deprives me of others, the same happens with `awk`, but someone has told me that I can do it from right to left, but I don't know how to do it.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -r 's/(linux)|(\.)//g;s/ /\n/gp' file
```

First remove any occurrences of "linux" or full stop and then replace spaces for new lines.